# Linear transformation from one section of a circle to another: does it exist?

Tags: linear-transformations

I have a circle of radius 100 of which I am only considering integer coordinates. Is there a linear transformation I can apply to map any given point from the blue area (the blue area includes the red area) to the red area?

[image]

Comment: What is your definition of linear transformation? Usally these are from vector spaces to vector spaces... Are these sets vectors spaces?

Comment: Essentially I just want a function which can map an (x, y) point from the blue area to an (x, y) point to the red area, with the corners mapping to the corners i.e. (10, ~99) -> (30, ~95), (10, 10) -> (30, 20), (~99, 10) -> (~98, 20) and everything else scaled linearly in between.

Comment: A linear transformation that takes the three corners of the blue region to the three corners of the red region is going to take at least some of the curved boundary of the blue region and put it outside the red region.